# Django: how to count inner `sub_comment_set`?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

how to count the inner `sub_comment_set` that nested in ManyToManyField.
the nested objects comes from `comment = models.ManyToManyField(Comments)`

it would be great if anybody could help me what i am trying to solve. thank you so much in advance.

models.py:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class SubComments(models.Model):
    comment = models.ManyToManyField(Comments)
```

serializers.py:

```
class CommentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subcomments_set = SubCommentsSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = [
            "id", "post_title", "name", "cover", "email", "subject",
            "subcomments_set",
            
        ]
```

views.py

```
class CommentListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Comments
    queryset = Comments.objects.filter(status=1)
    serializer_class = CommentsSerializer

class SubCommentListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = SubComments
    queryset = SubComments.objects.filter(status=1)
    serializer_class = SubCommentsSerializer
```

API data:

```
[
  {
        "id": 2,
        "post_title": "chilika_photography_02",
        "name": "kimberly",
        "cover": "/media/author_cover/batman.jpg",
        "email": "kimberlypatino01@gmail.com",
        "subject": "kimberly messages...",
        "subcomments_set": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "zatty",
                "email": "zatty@gmail.com",
                "subject": "zatty messages02....",
                "datetime": "08/05/2020"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "zatty",
                "email": "zatty@gmail.com",
                "subject": "zatty messages04....",
                "datetime": "08/05/2020"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you share your views.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prefetch_related + annotate:

example:

```
Comments.objects.prefetch_related('sub_comments_set').annotate(count=Count('sub_comments_set'))
```

Edited:

Override queryset on viewset

```
class CommentListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Comments
    queryset = Comments.objects.filter(status=1)
    serializer_class = CommentsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
         return Comments.objects.prefetch_related('sub_comments_set').annotate(count=Count('sub_comments_set'))
```

Comment: okay in your views, and override the def get_queryset()

Comment: but there have no object attribute 'prefetch_related' in my models

Comment: prefetch_related is part django orm. I should be fine

Comment: so my views will be `queryset = Comments.objects.prefetch_related('sub_comments_set').annotate(count=Count('sub_comments_set'))` ?

Comment: I updated above, if you wanted to display the count, just add "count" on your serializer fields

Comment: where do you calling the `Count`, it throwing `NameError`.

Comment: add from django.db.models import Count

Comment: now it's throwing `Cannot resolve keyword 'sub_comments_set' into field`. do i have to give a related_name `sub_comments_set`  in `SubComments` model?

Comment: add related_name='sub_modules', then change the prefetch to sub_modules

Comment: now it's throwing an AttributeError: `when attempting to get a value for field 'subcomments_set' on serializer 'CommentsSerializer'.`

Comment: its now sub_comments instead of subcomments_set, its because of related_name

Comment: it's returning the same as usual i was getting the value before. no changes in value!

Comment: do you use any remote desktop application like teamviewer or anydesk to share live code ?